# How to set date breaks to the 1st of each month in ggplots

Tags: date, ggplot2, time-series

Is there a way I can get the dates to break on the 1st of each month. I want to set the labels as (%b %y) but as you can see from the image the first break is 30 Jun 19 so would read as Jun 19 but I need this to read as Jul 19.

```
rdate<-as.POSIXct(DUN$Date)
D<-ggplot(DUN,aes(x=rdate,y=Average.density..g.cm3.))+geom_point(colour="red",size=2)+
  ylab("density g/m3") + xlab(NULL)+ coord_cartesian(ylim=c(1,2))+scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,10,0.1))+
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "2 month", labels = date_format("%d %b %y"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjpu6.png)

Comment: Hello @Hannahc. It would help that you  give a reproducible example. Otherwise, it is difficult to give you an answer. But an idea would be to use `breaks` instead of `date_breaks` and `seq` with dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can set breaks like this

`seq(Sys.Date(),Sys.Date()+100,by="month")`